# Why is an algebraic field defined with $+ - * /$ rather than other operations?

Tags: abstract-algebra

In mathematics, a "field" is defined as below (not a strict one):

- a set of elements.
- For any $2$ elements within the set, the $+ - * /$
  operations will map to another element within the same set.

My understanding is:

Mankind has the **intuitive** sense of quantity. So we tend to abstract concrete objects into numbers. And then we can reach interesting conclusions about the objective world through operating the numbers.

My questions is:

Why are **only** $4$ operations picked up when defining the field? Any other options? Why didn't we pick up the **root extraction** or **power** operation for example?

Comment: Power operation is simply multiplication.

Comment: @DonLarynx Indeed. Maybe "power" is not a good example here. But we can definitely define many different operations.

Answer (score 7):

I think you're looking at it backwards. You make it sound as if an entity of field has always existed, people just chose what operations to populate it with. While in reality the algebraic structures with 4 operations mentioned popped up in so many places in mathematics that it warranted for such an algebraic structure to have a name - thus the field was born. Now why would an algebraic structure with these 4 operations pop up in different branches of math and why would it need to have a name? To answer that question, I wouldn't look at the field as an entity containing 4 operations. I would look at it as one with 2 operations, that is + and *. Other two are inverse operations of + and *. Now having only 2 operations it's in a sense the second simplest algebraic structure there is, the only simpler one would be group, that is a structure with a single operation.

Comment: Thanks. Indeed, it seems I misunderstand the order of *cause* and *consequence*. If looked at it in the right order, it is easier to comprehend *the born of field*.

Comment: I don't agree with "Now having only 2 operations it's in a sense the second simplest algebraic structure there is, the only simpler one would be group, that is a structure with a single operation." The most fundamental algebraic structure is that of a monoid. Suitably internalized, almost every algebraic structure is "made up out of" monoids. If one doesn't like units, one may say the same about semigroups. After monoids, we have groups, then abelian groups, then rings, then commutative rings, and finally fields ... fields are not the "second simplest algebraic structure".

Comment: I agree with you, but I didn't want to complicate things. I just wanted to show that if your order algebraic structures in accordance with the number of operations in them, then fields fall in the second simplest category in terms of number of operations, so it's kinda natural that these algebraic structures pop up everywhere and that some of them pop up so often that they warrant devising names for them.

Answer (score 2):

The Greeks implicitly considered the field of [constructible numbers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constructible_number), which is the smallest set of numbers closed under the ordinary arithmetic operations *and* square roots; it is the [quadratic closure](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratically_closed_field) of the rational numbers.

So, this earliest example of field does indeed consider other operations.

Comment: I really appreciate looking at this question from a historical perspective. Without history, math will most probably be taken as a set of predefined rules. Luckily for those take it for granted but dirsturbingly for those need more logical explanation.